# Signalr scaleout with sql server

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-backplane, signalr-2

We need to implement the push notification using Signalr. We have two web servers (i.e., production and the backup server configured in cluster). The client will be connected to the backup server only if the production server is down. We have production database and backup database which are synchronized. The production web server is connected with the production database and backup web server is connected with the backup database. How to scaleout this scenario with sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link which sums up the scale out in three different methods:

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server